# How to use variable in string in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use a variable in a string. I have tried to do it many times, but it is only getting the variable name.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
          $("a").click(function(){
           var id= $(".id").html();
           $('.html').html("<div class='new' id=+id+>jitender</div>")
             });
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">Make Html</a>
      <div class="html"></div>
      <div class="id">first</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Concatenating can be done with `+` as follows.

```
$(".html").html('<div class="new" id="' + id + '">jitender</div>");
```

or in the modern world you can use template strings:

```
$(".html").html(`<div class="new" id="${id}">jitender</div>`);
```

The more jQuery-oriented approach would be:

```js
var id = "some-id";

$("<div>", {
    "class": "new",
    id: id,
    text: "jitender"
}).appendTo(".html");
```

```css
.new {
    background: #f0f;
}
#some-id {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="html"></div>
```

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#string_operators
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @amit This is string concatenation. You can read about it in [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators).

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data directly into HTML.  You aren't escaping anything, opening yourself up to invalid HTML and injection issues.

Comment: @Brad Arbitrary data? When did the local node contents become an arbitrary data? In this example the value of variable `id` is just the inner markup of another DOM element, not the cookie/input/query_string value. Generally, your comment does make sense, but only as a side note, that has nothing to do with the string concatenation *problem* raised here. I am very glad that you (and your friend) found this old useless question (worth closing as 'this-doesn't-work-help-me-I-don't-want-to-learn') in the SO trash bin tagged 'JavaScript' and spent your time and 12+ points for downvoting.

Comment: @VisioN Remember that your answers will be used in other contexts than the literal code from the question.  Especially in the case of markup on the page, if you want to use that as text in the context of HTML, you would want to make sure any HTML entities are escaped properly. For what it's worth, this question and your answer were linked to from another similar question.  I downvoted your answer because it provides no warning of the context in which it can be used. My comment is to warn folks. Finally, I don't know who my "friend" is. Others can vote as they please.  Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Brad Yes, now I see that this question was used for the close vote. My apologies for the "friend", of course you have nothing to do with the other votes. I don't take things personally, I was completely confused, as I never expected such questions *ever* be found and linked to.

Comment: @Brad Regarding the point raised in your comment, I think that 90% of answers don't contain all possible warnings  for the cases when the solution is used in the wrong way. Following this logic we must mention about all vulnerabilities just in case if someone wants to add e.g. Ajax support or whatever. The current context was not so implicit to warn in advance about this, as the source of the data is rather visible.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use template literals:

```
$('.html').html(`<div class='new' id=${id}>jitender</div>`)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Not supported by Internet Explorer

Answer (score 3):

I felt this to be a more easy and efficient way. (use ``)

```
$(".html").html(`<div class="new" id="${id}">jitender</div>`)
```

Comment: The quotes around ${id} are not right. In addition, IW does not support that method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
    var id= $(".id").html();
    $('.html').html("<div class='new' id='"+id+"'>jitender</div>");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing this is is by taking advantage of jQuery's HTML constructor to perform all the necessary escaping for you:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var id= $(".id").html();
    // create new element
    $('<div>', { 
        class:'new', 
        id: id, 
        text: 'jitend'
    }).appendTo('.html'); // and append it
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(".html").html("<div class='new' id='"+id+"'>jitender</div>")
```

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data directly into HTML.  You aren't escaping anything, opening yourself up to invalid HTML and injection issues.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript does not support expanding variables inside double quotes. Close (and reopen) the quotes and use the + operator, as you already did.

`"<div class='new' id='" + id  + "'>"`

here `id` is variable

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data directly into HTML. You aren't escaping anything, opening yourself up to invalid HTML and injection issues.