# Read HTML "id" attribute from variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
var id = column[columnIndex];
row.append($('<td id = "+id"/>').html(value));
```

This is reading id as a string. I need it to read it from the variable i stored it in(id). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, use string concatenation: `"foo" + str`.

Comment: There's no magic in jQuery selectors. They are just regular text!

Comment: Folks, concatenation is the wrong solution here... unless you plan on escaping whatever `id` is yourself, which you shouldn't bother doing.  jQuery has a perfectly good `.attr()` method.

Comment: @Brad: You are right, setting the ID in a different way would be ideal. However, which ID contains quotation marks? There is not much to escape (I might be missing something of course).

Comment: @FelixKling We don't know where that ID comes from, and we don't know where it will come from in the future.  The code manipulating the DOM should be completely transparent.  Besides, folks copy/paste code from Stack Overflow all the time without understanding what they're doing.  I want to make sure that the answer is fully correct, assuming nothing about the input data.  Bugs and security issues arise all the time because code used in one context is modified to work in another down the road, and assumptions were made up front.

Comment: @Brad: Reopened and upvoted your answer. It's still sad that this question had to be asked in the first place.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks Felix.  And yes, agreed.

Comment: @FelixKling [What the heck is going on here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049275/how-to-use-variable-in-string-in-jquery/11049291#comment38384514_11049291) Got a bunch of downvotes for the old useless answer `:D`

Comment: @VisioN: `:(` I closed this question as duplicate of yours at first and I guess you got caught in the crossfire. Sorry `:-/`/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element attributes are always strings.  That being said, your code won't work at all anyway.  I think you are expecting string interpolation.  Try this instead:

```
row.append($('<td>').attr('id', id).html(value));
```

Comment: alt: `$('<td>',{id:id,html:value}).appendTo(row);`

Comment: @BradChristie Wouldn't your suggestion add an attribute called `html` to the tag?

Comment: This makes jQuery take care of escaping, thus your code will not break when `id` contains stuff like quotes.

Comment: @Brad: have a look at the docs. The second parameter allows you to apply the values against the keys (in this case they're property and method names).

Comment: Why the downvote?  If anyone thinks this answer is incorrect, you should point out why.

Comment: Brad: The [mentioned docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding it as a variable:

```
var id = column[columnIndex];
row.append($('<td id="' + id + '"/>').html(value));
```

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data directly into HTML.  You aren't escaping anything, opening yourself up to invalid HTML and injection issues.

Comment: nothing to worry about if you are not getting that "id" from a client input

Comment: That's not true at all!  What if my application had IDs like `< something >`?  `234&567`?  Security is only one aspect of why escaping data is important.

Comment: Escaping data is great and necessary, when data comes from a client input. You are escaping something that maybe you dont need to escape. That depends on where the `id` variable comes from, and you dont know that, so your comment maybe ok, and maybe not (the same with mine). Thats my point

Comment: Knowing when to escape is important. @lante has a point that it should be a decision based on the specific case. Generally, I would say its a bad idea to be using `id`s that need to be escaped when working in HTML. Of course there are exceptions but blindly escaping all input is not smart coding either.

Answer (score -1):

```
var id = column[columnIndex];
row.append( $('<td id="' + id + '">').html(value) );
```

Test and Enjoy!!

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data directly into HTML.  You aren't escaping anything, opening yourself up to invalid HTML and injection issues.

Comment: Hahahaha, not really, If you go to the source code of jQuery to get data using the ID is not escaping anything...For what you're doing that really is not necessary as you're not doing anything with the data server.

Comment: That isn't true at all.  If you use text in the context of HTML, you must escape or all your usage of reserved entities is ambiguous.  If you could reference the source code you speak of, I'll either try to explain why it isn't an issue in that context, or will file a jQuery bug.

Comment: Brad, man ... go to jQuery 2.1.0 and check the data and check the format method please!

Believe me, I'm sure of what I say

Comment: I believe that you are sure of what you say, that's obvious.  Let me provide an example.  Suppose `var id = '"><img src="http://example.com/image.png'`.  Obviously, nobody is going to make such an ID, but my point is that your code is not transparent.  Suppose your site has a parameter to accept an ID as input which is only used client-side.  Someone sends out an e-mail with a link to your login page, containing a nice `/yoursite#id=%3Cscript%20src%3D%22somethingevil.js%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E`, and then uses this to steal everyone's passwords?

Comment: You do not do validation in the backend? 
Because that is a thing of someone who believes that everything is done in the frontend :P

Comment: In my example it's an anchor fragment which never makes it to the server.  There are plenty of web applications where nearly everything **is** done client-side.  Validate all you want, client-side or server-side, but some day you're going to work on an application that will need to accept some variable input.  A more practical example... pre-fill a text field.  Are you going to concatenate that into `<input />`?  Of course not.