# How do i pass the value from a variable to .html() using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this change function in jquery when selecting the time, the time will calculate to four hours. Upon selecting using change function the time and calculate for four hours works well. Now my problem is how will i able to pass the value to my `.html()`

Here is my script below:

```
 $('#changeTime').change(function() {
            $("#checkoutT").hide();
            var time = $(this).val();


            var timeArr = time.split(":");

            var timevar = timeArr[0];

            var x = <?php echo $minStayExp[0] ?>;
            var calc = parseInt(timevar) + parseInt(x);

            console.log(timevar);
            console.log(calc);
            alert(calc);


            $("#checkoutTime").html('<p class="text-sm text-muted"></p>');


         });
```

Now i want my `value` in my `var calc` will passed to `.html()` line of code in here:

```
$("#checkoutTime").html('<p class="text-sm text-muted"> + calc +</p>');
```

Something like this.

Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: basic string concatenation. `'<p class="text-sm text-muted">' + calc + '</p>'` You did not close the strings....

Comment: thank you i forgot its concatenation

Comment: it works now! thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use variable in string in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049275/how-to-use-variable-in-string-in-jquery)

Comment: Yes it answers my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concat.

```
$("#checkoutTime").html('<p class="text-sm text-muted">' + calc +'</p>');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use string interpolation:

```
$("#checkoutTime").html(`<p class="text-sm text-muted">${calc}</p>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in your concatenation

```
'<p class="text-sm text-muted">' + calc + '</p>
```